# htaccess custom php.ini vs php_value or php_flag

Tags: .htaccess, php-ini

I want to setup `xdebug` php extension to my project. I have a linux enviroment and there are others who work on the same server. I want to do this via custom `php.ini` file setup in `.htaccess` file. I have some questions about this:

1. Will my custom `php.ini` file has to be a copy of the original `php.ini` file in order to modify only what I need? Or it will be enough to have in that file only the settings I want to change?
2. As I have experimented, it is good to have the setting `SetEnv PHPRC /path/to/my/custom/phpinifile` above all other settings in `.htaccess` file. What about the manual settings `php_value` or `php_flag` below `SetEnv`? Will they overwrite my `php.ini` file settings?

Comment: Why do you need a custom `php.ini` file? I think using the global configuration over-written by a `.htaccess` should be sufficient for most of cases.

Comment: The problem is that I work on a server where many others work as well. I don't want to interfere with their projects.

Comment: Do you know that you can have as many `.htaccess` as you want in a server? Doesn't your project resides in a subfolder of its own? Then you can have a specific `.htaccess` in your project's subfolder and it won't conflict with any other project's configuration. I can not see a scenario in which this won't work!

Comment: I wasn't talking about `.htaccess` file, I was talking about setting up `xdebug` in the main `php.ini` file. It is not acceptable.

Comment: @Mehran, .htaccess has many limitations. Some settings can only be changed by php.ini

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you need to know there are different ways your webserver can be configured to make use of PHP. Personally I have experienced with mod_php and FastCGI so I can brief you on these two. These are called handlers and they affect hugely how you can configure PHP.

**mod_php**

If you've installed PHP as a module of Apache, the `php.ini` file is read when the Apache starts. In this case, all the major PHP directives like `zend_extension` and `extension` will be applied when Apache is starting thus they can not be set within a `.htaccess` file. In my experience the `SetEnv PHPRC` in the `.htaccess` does not work either.

**FastCGI**

In this case the `php.ini` file is loaded each time a request arrives. So if you change PHP's configuration, you don't need to restart Apache. Yet you can not set major PHP directives like `zend_extension` and `extension` in a `.htaccess` file and they need to be set in `php.ini` file. This is because when `.htaccess` is applied, the PHP extensions are already listed and loaded and changing those directives will have no effect (it will result in no error either). But the good news is that in this mode you can use `SetEnv PHPRC` in `.htaccess` file. So you can point to a custom `php.ini` file which will load xdebug indeed.

There's [another way](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) you can load user specific `php.ini` files too. But I haven't tested it yet so I can not comment either it's useful in your case or not. Perhaps you can take a look at it yourself. But it is mentioned in the page that it works only in CGI / FastCGI too.

**Bottom line**

If you are using mod_php, you've got no choice but to modify the original `php.ini` to load xdebug. But you can enable it per each virtual host putting enable commands in appropriate `.htaccess` files.

If you are using FastCGI, you can either load xdebug in original `php.ini` or you can have your own `php.ini` file and point to it in `.htaccess` file (yet in either case xdebug is loaded in a `php.ini` file). But if you're using the later case, your original `php.ini` will not be applied at all. So you need to mention whatever directive you want in you own version of `php.ini` file. Again you can turn on / off xdebug for each virtual host within `.htaccess` files.

Whichever solution you'll choose, you need to enter this in your `php.ini` file to load the xdebug:

```
zend_extension = /path/to/your/xdebug.so
```

And this one in your virtual host's `.htaccess` to enable debugging:

```
php_value xdebug.profiler_enable 1
```

**[UPDATE]**

How to check if your server is running PHP in mod_php or FastCGI:

Look for **Server API** in `phpinfo`'s output. If it reads `Apache 2.0 Handler` it's mod_php while in FastCGI it will read `CGI/FastCGI`.

Comment: I think you have a complete answer so I don't want to aswer over it. Maybe you can add that he can create several environment using the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php so it will be easier to add specific configuration to the project. But it can't be use to add new module like xdebug of course because you will need an /etc/init.d/apache2 restart command

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how `getEnv` fits in this picture! Personally, I've used `getEnv` to pass parameters to my code as some configuration but I don't see how this can be used to load an extension (as you said yourself). So I'm not sure if it is relevant here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In fact it can't load an extension but you could de fine some .ini values that you will set using ini_set inside a bootsrap file

Comment: I believe that's an overkill, because you can set whatever ini directives you want in `.htaccess` instead of setting them as environment variables and read them in your bootstrap. Personally I've used environment variables only for one purpose; and that's telling the code which section of application's configuration should be used (like `development` or `production`). As it is instructed in Zend Framework's tutorial.

Comment: I just though about Zend too. I know that is not the best way but when you are in specific context like his one you can do that tricks. The best way would be to make son specific environement. But you write this is not the best way to do.

Comment: @Mehran: thanks for all the info. Will the `php.ini` file have to be a copy of the original `php.ini` file?

Comment: @machineaddict: I know it's not obvious but it's been said in the answer that if you introduce your customized version of `php.ini` file the original is discarded completely. So you need to set all you need in your own version from scratch.

Comment: I think the server is setup with `mod_php` as I couldn't load a custom `php.ini` file with `.htaccess`. I'm going to have to modify the main `php.ini`

Comment: I've just updated my answer so you can make sure how your PHP is installed.